# How to make Parse's "done" callback to be called immediately when network is unavailable

Tags: android, parse-platform

The title says it all.

I have a table on the Parse server, I fill it manually, then in my app I want to count then query it like this:

```
mCurrentParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(FavoriteTable.NAME);
mCurrentParseQuery.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
mCurrentParseQuery.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
    }
});
```

As I have tested, it seems Parse listens on event when network become available then starts the query, so when network is unavailable (either Wifi or data connection) `done` callback never gets called.

My question is how to make Parse call `done` callback immediately when network is unavailable, even with a ParseException.

Comment: I think more appropriate pattern would be to check network status right before making the call.

Comment: I guessed so but I noticed Parse requires ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission, maybe they have some settings for this.

Comment: @LeoLink I think they need this permission for pushes. So it's easy to check connection prior executing request

Comment: @OlegOsipenko oh okay. So back to my main question, the best practice now is checking network state by myself before making any Parse query?

Comment: @LeoLink think so. Cause all you need you get from Android Framework - ConnectivityManager etc.